# Combining WHEN and aggregation functions

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to convert this pyspark SQL code sample:

```
df = df.groupby("id").agg(expr(
"""
CASE
    WHEN last(a) IS NULL THEN first(a)
    ELSE last(a)
    END AS a
"""))
```

Into a fully dataframe code without SQL expression. I tried:

```
df = df.groupby("id").agg(
    when(last("a").isNull, first("a"))
    .otherwise(last("a"))
    .alias("a"))
```

> TypeError: condition should be a Column

But obviously, it's not working. What am I doing wrong? Any suggestion will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `isNull` to check, not `is None`:

```
df = df.groupby("id").agg(
    when(last("a").isNull(), first("a"))
    .otherwise(last(col("a")))
    .alias("a"))
```

Comment: I already tried, that produce the same error.

Comment: You didn't have empty parenthesis after `isNull`.